# How to make second default _Layout view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, layout, master-pages

I'm working on `ASP.NET MVC 4` application which has user part and admin panel. For the user part I use the default `_Layout` view but in my `Views` folder I have subfolder `Admin` where I plan to set all my views for the admin panel and I want a different layout for them, let's say - `_AdminLayout`. For now I use:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml"; 
}
```

on top of each view in the `Admin` folder, but I wonder if there's a way to set `_AdminLayout` as default layout only for those views that are inside this folder and thus get rid of the explicit declaration for each view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**~/Views/Admin/_ViewStart.cshtml**

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}
```

You can place a `_ViewStart` in any of the controller view folders to override the parent one. Convention makes it look to the most local path first, then proceed to Shared.

As an aside, you may want to look in to using areas to keep it compartmentalized, but that's really up to you and how you want to structure your project.

Comment: Using second `_ViewStart` did the job. If it's not a problem for you would you be more specific about using areas and for what. It's my first project where I have to plan everything myself and I'm open to different suggestions.

Comment: [MVC Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are a way of breaking your application in to compartmentalized portions based on different functionality. e.g. Consider a website (~/) with a blog (~/Areas/Blog), forums (~/Areas/Forums) and maybe online market (~/Areas/Market). Now each has their own set up controllers and views without worry about overlap.